# Is this number an integer, an irreducible fraction, or an irrational number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I just want to know if I'm thinking correctly when I make these assertions:

If u and v are positive integers with v > 1, and gcd( u, v) = 1, then:

sqrt( u/v) is either an irreducible fraction,

```
for example, sqrt( 9/25) = 3/5
```

or an irrational number,

```
for example, sqrt( 9/5) = 3/sqrt(5)
```

It follows that:

```
sqrt( u/(5*v)) is either an irreducible fraction or an irrational number.
```

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: So, your observation is that $\sqrt{u/v}$ is either rational but not an integer, or irrational.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Every real number is an integer, an irreducible fraction or an irrational number...

Answer (score 2):

If $u$ and $v$ have no common factors other than $1$, then they are coprime and $\frac{u}{v}$ is irreducible. $\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{v}}$  will only be a fraction of integers if $u$ and $v$ are both square (or if they are equal). If this is the case, then $\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{v}}$ is irreducible (as $u$ and $v$ had no common factors to begin with and can't have gained any). If they aren't integers, there will remain a radical and thus, $\frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{v}}$ will be irrational.

So you are correct.